# How can I create a table that updates an ArrayList every time a user enters a value in Java?

Tags: java, listener

I have 2 columns, x and y. Every time a user edits a column, I would like for that data to be appended to that columns respective ArrayList (for x, xValues, for y, yValues). From reading the Oracle tutorial on Tables and TabelModels, I assume that I would need to add some kind of listener to the table. How would I do that? This is my code thus far:

```
public class MainTable extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5093783987473381647L;
private ArrayList<Integer> xValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Integer> yValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public MainTable() {
    super(new GridLayout(1,0));
    createFrame();

    JTable table = new JTable(new TheTabelModel());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    add(scrollPane);
}

class TheTabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1698344960140377275L;
    private String[] columnNames = {"x", "y"};
    private Object[][] data = {
            {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

private void createFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(510, 200));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly implement a trigger to call a Java function, which in turn updates your ArrayList in your Java code?

Check the following: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call2.htm

The procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_sal (
  emp_id NUMBER, old_sal NUMBER, new_sal NUMBER)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'DBTrigger.logSal(int, float, float)';
```

The trigger, which calls the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sal_trig
AFTER UPDATE OF sal ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.sal > 1.2 * old.sal)
CALL log_sal(:new.empno, :old.sal, :new.sal);
```

You can set your trigger to run on update, such that every time the user makes the update, it calls the function, which in turn updates the ArrayList.

Comment: I am not using SQL - this would all just be happening during runtime. I don't need to store the values after termination.